# "Autolog" override built in "object"

Tags: python, logging, built-in

I work on a legacy code without logs, and I looking for a way to log all method calls.

Is it possible to override the built in "object" in python ?

I tried the following code :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)

        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
                print('before calling %s' %attr.__name__)
                result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                print('done calling %s' %attr.__name__)
                return result
            return newfunc
        else:
            return attr

object = Foo

class Bar():
    def myFunc(self, data):
        print("myFunc: %s"% data)


bar = Bar()
bar.myFunc(5)
```

But my class Bar doesn't inherit from "object".

output :

```
myFunc: 5
```

However, if I declare my class Bar like this, it works :

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)

        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
                print('before calling %s' %attr.__name__)
                result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                print('done calling %s' %attr.__name__)
                return result
            return newfunc
        else:
            return attr

object = Foo

class Bar(object):
    def myFunc(self, data):
        print("myFunc: %s"% data)


bar = Bar()
bar.myFunc(5)
```

output :

```
before calling myFunc
myFunc: 5
done calling myFunc
```

The default "object" can't be override ? what's happen here ?

Maybe you know a better solution ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why not just inherit Foo? `class Bar(Foo)`

Comment: you changed the reference of `object` afterwards. But that does not change the previous reference made before your change (or `Foo` would inherit from itself). BTW none of your examples work. I get an error when invoking `super`

Comment: @MiteshNinja because Bar already exists.

Comment: I think redefining the Bar `getattr` method would be better

Comment: Why are you trying to override `object`? Overriding object is far more unacceptable than reworking the *legacy methods*. Albeit, you could use decorators

Comment: @MosesKoledoye >> My goal is not to use this hack in production, but just to be able to generate logs to have a better comprehension of the code.

I my mind, it’s more like a profiler.

Comment: @MiteshNinja >> I don’t want to change the existing code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre >> It should be work on python3.